# Using reserved characters as argument to custom macro

Tags: symbols, characters

How can I get this work:

```
\namedinclude{perceptron\_multilayer.h}{Multi-layer perceptron class definition}
```

where `namedinclude` is defined as

```
\newcommand{\namedinclude}[2]{\subsection{#1}#2\lstinputlisting{#1}}
```

Currently I get an "Emergency stop".

Comment: `\subsection` doesn't take two arguments, but I guess that doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: The second argument should hold a description. Changed macro definition does not help.

Comment: `\lstinputlisting{a\_b}` is not allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A token like `\_` in the file name is not allowed, whereas `_` is.

You can do

```
\newcommand{\namedinclude}[2]{%
  \subsection{\texttt{#1}}%
  #2\par
  \begingroup\def\_{_}%
  \lstinputlisting{#1}%
  \endgroup
}
```

or

```
\newcommand{\namedinclude}[2]{%
  \subsection{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}%
  #2\par
  \lstinputlisting{#1}%
}
```

but, in this case, you do

```
\namedinclude{perceptron_multilayer.h}{Multi-layer perceptron class definition}
```

---

However, I'd see better this as an environment:

```
\usepackage{xparse}
\newenvironment{codesection}{m}
 {\subsection{\texttt{\detokenize{#1}}}}
 {\par\lstinputlisting{#1}}
```

and use this as

```
\begin{codesection}{perceptron_multilayer.h}
Multi-layer perceptron class definition
with more words.

Even a new paragraph.
\end{codesection}
```